# MySQL pivot table create activity log file with start, end time

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL.

I have a Set data like this.

```
     Tester     datetime_start      Event       Lot_Num
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 13:21     Down    
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 13:26     LoadTP      Lot_A
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 13:38     LotStart    Lot_A
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 16:19     LotEnd      Lot_A
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 16:19     Idle    
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 16:20     Down    
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 16:23     LoadTP      Lot_B
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 16:35     LotStart    Lot_B
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 17:12     Down        Lot_B
     Tester#1   20/9/2016 17:36     LotEnd      Lot_B
```

I Need help to make the data above to something looks like this:

```
    Tester      Lot_Num Time_Start      Time_End
    Tester#1    Lot_A   20/9/2016 13:26     20/9/2016 16:19
    Tester#1    Lot_B   20/9/2016 16:23     20/9/2016 17:36
```

I have no idea how to do and I try to do something like this.

```
    SELECT  Tester,Lot_Num,Event,
        (case when Event ='LoadTP' then datetime_start end)as Time_Start,
        (case when Event ='LotEnd' then datetime_start end)as Time_End

    from T_Utilization
```

But now my table looks like this.

```
                        Time_Start      Time_End
    Tester#1    Lot_A   20/9/2016 13:26 
    Tester#1    Lot_A                   20/9/2016 16:19
    Tester#1    Lot_B   20/9/2016 16:23 
    Tester#1    Lot_B                   20/9/2016 17:36
```

Need help on Mysql, Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
SELECT Tester, LotNum, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Event ='LoadTP' THEN datetime_start END) AS Time_Start,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Event ='LotEnd' THEN datetime_start END) AS Time_End
FROM T_Utilization
WHERE LotNum IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Tester, LotNum
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ec010/2)

Comment: Thanks. the solution is so simple! correct me if i am wrong. Is it the "Max" (conditional aggregation) to force Mysql to select specified one result?

Comment: @BenjaminLee Yes, it picks the one having `Event ='LoadTP'/'LotEnd'`.